# Using square brackets to concatenate things in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, concatenation, square-bracket

Anyone know why this isn't working?

```
$('#screen').css({
  'background-image': [bg_num == 1 ? 'josh' : 'jessi'] + '_background.jpg',
  'background-color': 'red'
 });
```

The background color is getting set, but the image is not.

I've not really had much practice using square brackets in Javascript to get this kind of thing done. Anyone have tips if I'm doing something way wrong? Or no of a nice explanation of their use?

EDIT: And just to be clear, the check itself is actually happening, because if I do the same thing in a console.log() is outputs "josh_background.jpg" just fine. It's just not taking in this css setting function.

Comment: I'm confused, what is it you think brackets mean in Javascript (hint: they are not equivalent to parentheses)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:**

What you were doing was creating an Array literal with the value `'josh'` or `'jessi'`, then concatenating `'_background.jpg'` onto it, so it technically would work.

The issue is that you're missing the `'url()'`  part of the `background-image` value.

```
'background-image': 'url(' + (bg_num == 1 ? 'josh' : 'jessi') + '_background.jpg)',
```

...but you should still use the `()` for grouping instead of constructing an Array.

---

**Original answer:**

Use parentheses for grouping instead of square brackets:

```
'background-image': (bg_num == 1 ? 'josh' : 'jessi') + '_background.jpg',
```

The only use you'll have for square brackets in javascript will be for getting/setting a property on an object, or for creating an Array literal:

```
var arr = []; // An Array literal

arr[10] = 'someArrValue'; // set index 10


var obj = {};  // A plain object literal

obj['prop'] = 'someObjValue';  // set the "prop" property

var key = 'prop2';

obj[key] = 'someOtherObjValue'; // set the property referenced in the "key" variable
```

*...oh, they have use in regular expression syntax of course...*

Comment: Note that `['jessi', 'josh'][bg_num] + '_background.jpg'` might work too :-)

Comment: @Pointy: True. More than one way to skin a cat. :o)

Comment: Still can't get the background change to actually take.

Comment: @Ian: Just realized that your code should still technically work, though parentheses would be better. The issue is that you don't have the `url()` part of the value that is needed for  the `background-image` property. I updated my answer.

Comment: Figured it out. Needed the "url(*)" around the url.

Comment: Although I do have another question: Using the same parenthesis idea, would I be able to embed a switch condition instead of a ternary?

Comment: @Ian: Yeah, I was distracted by the Array and I missed the actual issue at first. Glad you got it working. :o)

Comment: @Ian: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You mean something like `((bg_num == 1 && 'josh') || 'jessi')` ?

Comment: Ah don't worry about it, solved it in much easier way. As usual, I'm a fool.